# UDP flooding multiple servers

Tags: udp, flooding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best techniques for preventing denial of service attacks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/3476/what-are-the-best-techniques-for-preventing-denial-of-service-attacks)

What do you suggest?

Being UDP flooded as I write to multiple servers in different data centers in 5 different countries . Up to 250,000 packets a second. I believe Cisco routers 5505 would not handle that - (some of our datacenter hosters can offer them. Some have no firewalls to offer.) Our clients naturally have constant disconnects to the server they are on. Hacker started this about three weeks ago. Sometimes for a few hours - up to a few days.

If we can't stop it hitting the server with firewalls then how do we stop the hacker - now there is the challenge!

Update : Found some of the data centers offer up to 10 firewall rules but would their routers be able to handle the possible volume I am talking about?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 2):

You need to get your ISP to drop this traffic on the backbone before it even hits your firewall/router. Once it's there, it's already consuming resources. Sure, you don't respond to requests if you block it at the firewall, but the rejected requests are still chewing up bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for your comments MDMarra. We don't believe however that any of the server companies will agree to drop this traffic on the backbone.

Comment: Then you need a new ISP.